How do I make a formatting rule for a pattern not containing a symbol to attach a rule to
I can define a formatting rule such as
Format[ex[ls_List], TeXForm] := "grgr"

But when I want to define such a formatting rule for a general patter, for example with a certain Head or member of a certain group, i.e.
Format[ex_?MemberQ[{example}, ex][ls_List], TeXForm] := "grgr"

I get an error that Format: (...) does not contain a symbol to attach a rule to.
How do I define formats of this type?

I thought for this case the workaround with writing List explicitly might work but even if the Format expression contains List, i.e.
Format[ex_?MemberQ[{example}, ex][{lss___}], TeXForm] := "grgr"

I get the same error. (I might have expected the Protected error if it tries to attach the pattern to List but it does not even try this.)

I don't think you can do this. Formatting has to be assigned to a certain head. So either map Format over your list: ex = {ex1, ex2, ex3}; (Format[#[ls_List], TeXForm] := "grgr") & /@ ex;, or create a wrapper for your symbols.

@Domen, thanks. Do you also understand why it can't be assigned to List in this example? (Apart from it being Protected which would require an Unprotect.) Edit: Oops see you can't even Unprotect List.

I guess it is what it is. It would have been nice if I could have attached the definition to TeXForm actually since that kinda makes sense.

It also seems MMA does not like to attach rules to Plus even though that doesn't have Locked. Format[Plus[args___], TeXForm] :=rhs gives the same error.
